# Unable to change directory in Ubuntu server

Tags: server, xubuntu, lts

I tried using the command `which python` and it gave me a directory

```
/home/user/bin/python
```

But when I `cd /home/user/bin/python` I get

```
bash: cd: python: Not a directory
```

I use Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS server.

Comment: why would you need to change directory to a file?

Comment: @RInzwind I just wanted to find the python executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `which` is never a directory, it is the full path of the executable *file* that will be called when you type `python` (or whatever command you gave as argument to `which`).

Therefore, the directory you can go to is only `/home/user/bin` and you will find an executable file named `python` in there.